# How to align a text/pargaph both to left and right in HTML?

Tags: html, css

How I can align a text/pargaph both to left and right in HTML? Like in the office programs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`text-align: justify;` in css

but beware: unlike in proffesional `DTP applications` or even in word, HTML/browser often do not play nicely with this - you might end having humongous gaps in your text, completely destroying any typogtaphy you try to achieve in your document.

**Edit:**

As reply to Brian, my experiences are following:

- haven't tried `%` for width, because I either set width in `px` or not at all and let `display:block;` element fill whole width of parent
- `text-align: justify` works best with small `font-size` with slightly higher `line-height` - `line-height` is for readbility and smaller font size puts more characters in one line (abstract characters-per-line width), therefore gaps between words/justified text looks better
- regarding images instead of small non changing parts of text - I tend to use as few image replacement parts as possible - I have very good results with `Cufón`, if you learn to count with it's cons
- I don't advice using justified text for sidebars and one-liners - it mostly seems **ugly**

**Edit2:**
The main problem is, that browsers don't know how to part your text (i.e. unbreakable to un-breakable) - soft hyphyen, `&shy;` should solve this (link: [soft hyphen overview](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/shy.html)), but browser support is *wild* at best :)

Comment: In regards to the having humongous gaps in text, I have found that text-align: justify; works best when you have a set font size, and a set width. If it is a percentage width, that can lead to very unexpected results. Likewise, if the font is not specified in an exact pixel value but a relative value, similarly unexpected results for various browsers can be experienced. Another solution if there is just a small area of text that doesn't change is to use an image.

Comment: @Brian My reply in answer, since it kind of touches the subject.

Comment: @Brian: +1 And of course there is the non-breaking humongous word issue that throws this (and even right- or left-aligned text containers) into a turmoil. One tries to adhere to the "alphabet-and-a-half" (i.e., approx. 40 characters) line width, which is the goal for printed matter, but that can get really ugly on the Web.

Comment: +1 also. I hate to be a typography nerd, but I really wish more Web developers would pay attention to niceties of typography, or at least avoid the egregious errors like this one that are so often seen.

Comment: @Robusto - I wish my typography skills & perception were better, but I notice, that wrong usage of `text-align: justify` often leads to gaps in text reminding teeth of really-long-time homeless (no offense to homeless people)